# printing only filename not permissions and date

Tags: c, file-io, filenames

I am reading in an archive file from Unix and I want to read the files in and print what files are inside the archive and just the filename. For an example, I need `hello.c` not `hello.c 123124123 001004002 1000 0`.

Here is the I have right now

```
input_fd = open(archive_name, O_RDONLY);


while( (read(input_fd, buf, BUF_SIZE)) > 0) {
    printf("%s\n", buf);
}
close(input_fd);
```

Comment: It was created using the unix command `ar`.

Comment: Are you trying to implement `nm -s`?

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing seems weird to me but if you have a C-string (you're printing `buf` in the code and it produces sensible output) you can try to NUL-terminate it:

```
char *p;

if ((p = strchr(buf, ' '))
    *p = 0;
printf("%s\n", buf);
```

Comment: Printing only up to the first space character will *probably* work, but remember that file name can legally contain spaces.  The `ar t` method in the other answer is more likely to work in all cases.  (Presumably if you have `ar` archives lying around, you have the `ar` command.)

Comment: @KeithThompson That's quite sensible, I wasn't thinking about filenames with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

How portable does your code need to be?  By far the simplest way to achieve the effect is to use the `ar` command itself.  To get the output you desire:

```
ar t archive
```

There have been many archive formats in existence, and there are still a number of variants in common use (AIX in particular is rather different from 'the rest').  There are different ways of handling long file names.  To read the archive accurately, you will need to be able to read the header, possibly the string list, skip over the pseudo-file related to library symbols that are defined, and then process each file header and skip over the file itself, repeating until the end of the archive.  When you read the header, you will need to split it appropriately to isolate just the name.